# Backbone event for click WITH CSS selector not firing

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I hate putting this question out there (along with the other million 'event not firing' questions) but for whatever reason, the other questions and their respective answers do not work for me.

Here's the template markup inside a script 'text/template' tag with id of 'display_template'

```
<div class="display_data">
    <a class="remove">X</a>
    <div class="grid_6">
            <%= Data %>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Backbone view in Coffeescript

```
$ ->
  class window.WebsiteView extends Backbone.View

    displayTemplate: _.template $('#display_template').html()

    events:
      'click .remove': 'clicked'

    render: ->
      $(@el).html @displayTemplate @model.toJSON()
      @

    clicked: ->
      console.log 'clicked'
```

**Update**

It looks like I might not be instantiating the View correctly, it gets set from a collection and a collection's view.

```
  class window.Websites extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Website


  class window.WebsitesView extends Backbone.View
    template: _.template $('<div />').html()

    render: ->
      $(@el).html @template
      @collection.each @renderWebsite
      @

    renderWebsite: (website) =>
      website.attributes.Index = @collection.indexOf website

      view = new WebsiteView
        model: website

      $(@el).append view.render().el
```

If I remove the css selector from the click event, the 'clicked' method will fire for the specific View but stops working once I add in the css selector.  I suspect it might have something to do with `@el` not being bound correctly but I'm stumped and I was hoping someone might point me in the right direction with my specific syntax.

Comment: How are you instantiating your MyView? The code is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8EmwS/

Comment: Updated where the view gets set, thanks for the help.

Comment: Do "Inspect Element" from your browser and see if `<a class="remove">X</a>` is in the markup like it's supposed to be. Also consider if anything else might be on top of it (in terms of z-index).

Comment: Yep, its definitely in the markup. I dont have anything that would be layered on top.

Comment: Two things occur to me: first, have you instrumented backbone internally with console.log()s to see what you're binding to?  Secondly, both examples have fairly broken template instantiations.  It would be more like `template: $('#templateid').html(); ... _.template(@template, @collection.toJSON());`  Remove parens at your coffeescript whim.

Comment: Nice meeting you tonight Elf. I'm certainly questioning my need for backbone and/or coffeescript right now but I'll definitely take a closer look at the _.template method calls

Comment: Another question: What is `@el`? You haven't set it directly, or specified `tagName` or `className`...

Comment: @el in this case is a `<div />` by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the Backbone source. In the `delegateEvents` method, we have:

```
if (selector === '') {
  this.$el.bind(eventName, method);
} else {
  this.$el.delegate(selector, eventName, method);
}
```

You say that when there's no selector, your code works; but when the selector is `'.remove'`, it doesn't.

One possibility: You're using an old version of jQuery. [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) was added in 1.4.2.

Another possibility: There could be another event handler, bound elsewhere, that's doing `preventDefault` or returning `false`, preventing the event from bubbling up to `el`. To find these, use your browser's inspector and go to "Event Listeners" on the `.remove` link and anything wrapped around it.

Comment: double checked the element and nothing was attached, I'm sure its a silly mistake on my part somewhere

Comment: This is probably the best answer in that this is where you should console.log() from, to see what and where you're binding to.

Answer (score 0):

See if adding a "preventDefault" call helps:

```
clicked: (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log 'clicked'
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. How could calling `event.preventDefault()` possibly affect whether the `console.log` line is run?

Comment: I was thinking that clicking on the `a` tag might trigger the ordinary browser behavior of initiating a new page request, which might mask the console.log output or prevent the current page from even executing further.